# Command Is Not Firing From VIew

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a windows store app using XAML, where I have a binding that is of type:

```
DelegateCommand<DomainObject>
```

I'm trying to bind a list of DomainObject's like the following.  Note the button in the item template, fires the StartCommand:

```
<ItemsControl
    x:Name="MyList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{StaticResource Para}">
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=Image}" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="300" />

                <Button Content="Start"
                    Command="{Binding Path=StartCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the view model, I have the following:

```
public DelegateCommand<DomainObject> StartCommand
{
    get { return _startCommand; }
    set
    {
        _startCommand = value;
                //method I use to fire the property changed event
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("StartCommand");
    }
}
```

I instantiate an instance of the command via:

```
StartCommand = new DelegateCommand<DomainObject>(StartSession);
```

However, when the button is clicked, it never fires the command... my breakpoint in StartSession is not hit.  Where have I gone wrong?  Is it how I setup the command or parameter?  I can't figure this out.  Also note that the item in the ItemsControl is bound to an instance of DomainObject, so I want to pass that as the CommandParameter, which is why I think I messed it up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because of the `DataContext` inside an `ItemTemplate`. The line:

```
<Button Content="Start"
        Command="{Binding Path=StartCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Will bind to the `StartCommand` property in the `DomainObject` class, not your View Model. Do bind to the correct DataContext (the one your `ItemsControl`, not your `ItemContainer` is bound to) a small adjustment is required:

```
<Button Content="Start"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.StartCommand, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

This way, the WPF binding will find the ancestor of type `ItemsControl`  and bind to the `DataContext.StartCommand` property (assuming the `DataContext` is your View Model).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I'm getting an error saying AncestorTYpe isn't supported within the windows store app...

Comment: In this case, you could try to replace the RelativeSource part with `ElementName=MyList`.

Comment: Thanks, ElementName was the solution.